# My confusion regarding vtable content

Tags: c++

In below code the statement "aptr->fun2() is not allowed." My queries are :-

1.What is the content of derived class vtable.
2. if base vptr accesses derived class vtable and if it contains function fun2() then why aptr->fun2() is not allowed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    virtual void fun1();            
};

void A::fun1()
{
    cout << "\n Class A fun1 function called. ";
}

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void fun1();
    virtual void fun2();  
};

void B::fun1()
{
    cout << "\n Class B fun1 function called";
}

void B::fun2()
{
    cout << "\n Class B fun2 function called";
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A* aptr =new B();
    aptr->fun1();
    aptr->fun2();//cannot be called
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Functions you declare virtual are inherited. It doesn't go up the class hierarchy, only down.

Comment: Actually,the confusion is if base class vptr access derived class vtable which contains fun2().Then why cant we  access fun2() using base ptr.

Comment: It doesn't access the derived class vtable at all. It uses the A class vtable, which does not have a `fun2()`.

Comment: ok ...now i got it.Thx JBL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `fun2` with `aptr` because that is a `A*`, you'd have to cast it first

```
static_cast<B*>(aptr)->fun2();
```

The `virtual` function `fun1` will handle calling the overloaded `B::fun1` off of `aptr`, but that does not mean that you can access methods specific to `B` without casting.

Comment: that means nothing to do with vtable

Answer (score 2):

`A` does not define a function `fun2()`, so there is no way to access it via a pointer to an `A`. What you are expressing in code is:

I have an `A`, which can do `fun1()`. I have a `B` which is an `A`, but can do `fun2()` in addition to that.

But just because your `B` can do `fun2()`, no other `A` has to be able to do this.If what you are aiming for was actually possible, all `A`s would have to be able to do `fun2()`. Casting down is possible here, but you should probably reconsider your design. The fact that you try to use `A`, but some `A`s need different treatment than others violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I agree A does not define fun2().But i am asking you that derived class vtable contains fun2() or not.And If you give address of derived object to base class pointer like "A* aptr =new B();".Then,base class vptr will access derive class vtable..so what the problem in accessing fun2() which is present in derived class vtable..

Comment: B's vtable does contain fun2. But, the vtable does not even come into play at this point. Since the static (compile time) type of the variable is A, and there is no function named fun2 for A, the compiler will fail to find a definition. What happens when a virtual function is compiled, is that the compiler inserts code to lookup the function at runtime using the object vtable. In your case this vtable would contain a function fun2 at runtime for the B object, but there is no way for the comipler to infer this from the static type.